# Postman no pasa de <Sending request...> al hacer POST

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Quiero implementar el < express-validator > pero POSTMAN no responde, se queda en < Sending request... > al hacer un POST y en consola no me sale ningún error. Sólo sé que es por el < express-validator > porque quitandolo todo anda bien, me registra a los usuarios o me manda el mensaje de correo ya registrado en caso de que asi sea.

Esto aparece en Consola (dejando express-validator):

```js
> backend_red_educativa@1.0.0 start
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Conexion al servidor correctamente en la url: 3700
```

Este es mi index.js

```js
require('dotenv').config(); //Para usar las variables de entorno


// Variables
const app = require('./app'); //Acceder a nuestra APP donde se configuran las rutas, cors, etc.
const { dbConnection } = require('./database/config'); //Conexión a la BD



dbConnection();



app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>{
    console.log("Conexion al servidor correctamente en la url: " +process.env.PORT);
});
```

Mi app.js

```js
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express'); //Libreria express
const app = express(); //Pasando libreria



// CORS - Middlewares
app.use(cors());



// Cargando RUTAS
const usuarios_rutas = require('./routes/usuarios');



//Middlewares
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit:'50mb', extended: true})); //Recibir datos por url
app.use(express.json({limit:'50mb'})); //Transformar Datos a JSON



// RUTAS
app.use('/api', usuarios_rutas);



//Exportar
module.exports = app; //Para poder usar todo el archivo app.js
```

Mi router usuario.js:

```js
// Importaciones
const { Router } = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator');
const { validarCampos } = require('../middlewares/validar-campos');



// RUTAS CONTROLLERS
const UsuariosController = require('../controllers/usuarios');



// VARIABLES
const router = Router();



// RUTAS GET
router.get('/usuarios', UsuariosController.getUsuarios);


// RUTAS POST
router.post('/registro', 
    [
        check('nombre', 'El nombre es obligatorio').not().isEmpty(),
        check('nickname', 'El nickname es obligatorio').not().isEmpty(),
        check('email', 'El correo es obligatorio').isEmail,
        check('password', 'La contraseña es obligatorio').not().isEmpty(),
        validarCampos,
    ], 
    UsuariosController.crearUsuario
);



module.exports = router;
```

Mi middleware validar-campos.js:

```js
const { response } = require('express');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const validarCampos = (req, res = response, next) =>{
    const errores = validationResult(req);

    if( !errores.isEmpty() ){
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            errors: errores.mapped()
        });
    }

    next();
}

module.exports =  {validarCampos};
```

Mi controller de usuarios.js:

```js
const { response } = require('express');
const Usuario = require('../models/usuario');


const controller = {
    getUsuarios: async(req, res) => {
        const usuarios = await Usuario.find({}, 'nickname');

        res.json({
            ok: true,
            usuarios
        });
    },
    
    
    
    crearUsuario: async(req, res = response) => {
        const { nombre, nickname, email, password, } = req.body;

        try {
            const existeEmail = await Usuario.findOne({ email });
            
            if (existeEmail) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    msg: 'Correo ya está registrado.'
                });
            }
            
            const usuario = new Usuario(req.body);
            await usuario.save();

            res.json({
                ok: true,
                usuario
            });
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                msg: 'Error inesperado.... revisar logs'
            })
        }
    }
}



module.exports = controller;
```

Mi modelo de usuarios.js:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const UsuarioSchema = new Schema(
    {
        nombre: {
            type: String,
            required: true // El campo es obligatorio
        },
        nickname: {
            type: String,
            required: true, 
            trim: true, // Los espacios serán eliminados
            unique: true // El elemento debe ser unico y no repetirse
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: 'USER_ROLE'
        },
        google: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        materias: {
            type: String,
            materias: {
                nombre: {
                    type: String
                }
            }
        },
        verificado: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        img: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true //Guardar la fecha de creación y de actualización
    }
);


module.exports = model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);
```

Dependencias del package.json

```js
 "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi **router usuario.js** me faltaban unos < () > al final de mi < .isEmail >.